# How to unit test the download file name in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-storage

I am developing a Laravel application. I have developed a file download feature in my Controller like this.

```
public function downloadUsagePdf()
{
   return Storage::disk('default')->response('path/to/usage.pdf', 'new-file-name.pdf');
}
```

As you can see above, I am renaming the file. I like to unit test that the file is rendered with the new name. How can I unit test that? I am not downloading. I am just rendering on the browser first.

Answer (score 0):

The way I made it work was by doing this in the ControllerTest file:

```
$header = $response->headers->get('content-disposition');

$this->assertEquals($header, "attachment; filename=new-file-name.pdf");
```

Hopefully someone knows an easier way to do this

Comment: `$response->assertHeader('content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=new-file-name.pdf');`